# How do I use an API?

Tags: php, json

I'm not much of a programmer but I want to integrate http://storify.com/ into my site by pulling a story and displaying it.

I've been reading http://dev.storify.com/api/summary but it doesn't make much sense to me.

I'm guessing by this -

> "Writes are performed using POST and reads are performed using GET. All data is sent as JSON:"

... I need to send a HTTP request with a GET or POST and then parse the JSON response into something readable?

I'm not sure what to do from here.  Please help.

Comment: Tip: This question's far too vague - break down what you're trying to do into smaller chunks and ask something specific about some code you've actually written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the example:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.storify.com/v1'));

print_r($data);
```

Which produces following result:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [content] => stdClass Object
        (
            [status] => up
            [version] => 1.6.33
            [sha] => 93689c7b
            [uptime] => 1277
            [started_at] => 2012-06-13T12:07:54.496Z
            [memoryUsage] => 47M
            [env] => production
            [host] => storify-api02
        )

    [code] => 200
)
```

You can use $data object like this:

```
echo $data->content->host;
```